# What is (finiteness) tag intended for?

Tags: discussion, tagging

When checking [new tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new), I've noticed [finiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finiteness) tag there. At the moment there is [only one question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436763/interesting-finite-cardinality-theorems) in that tag. The tag creator [seems to be Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/436763/revisions) - unless it was created in another question, which has been retagged in the meantime.

Both tag-wiki and tag-excerpt are empty, so it is not clear what kind of questions this tag is intended for.
If everything about finite sets and finite structures were lumped under the same tag, it would not be a very useful tag (at least in my opinion).
For example, we have many questions about various definition of finiteness (which are not equivalent in ZF). But I do not know whether this is what the tag creator intended this tag for.

I think it would be good to create tag-wiki or at least tag-excerpt soon. They can guide the users when tagging. If we do it soon enough, we can avoid having plenty of off-topic questions in that tag. (But we need to clarify first what is on-topic there.)

> - What would you suggest as an appropriate content of the [finiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finiteness) tag?
> - Do we need the [finiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finiteness) tag?

Comment: Do we really need such a tag?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker That is another question that can be discussed in this thread. (But at least the tag creator probably thinks, that it is a reasonable tag.)

Comment: @Michael: No. We don't need this sort of tag.

Comment: I looked at that tag when it was first created. I don't really see a need for it, but I let it be because _I don't know how else should one tag the question currently tagged [tag:finiteness]_. I didn't want to leave it with just (big-list)...

Comment: I think it'd be better to find a more fitting tag for the question than creating a new one.

Comment: I support deleting the tag.

Comment: I thought the question rather vague in the first place and was mildly surprised that no one voted to close it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Such as? (Oddly, the tag seems to be a good fit here, and yes, one is left with the vague feeling that a better tag may be hiding somewhere.)

Comment: @Andres: I don't have a positive result. Just negative ones at the moment.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I've given some suggestions [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/10275340#10275340), but I did not like any of them too much. (The question would fit only marginally in those tags.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks for the link.

Comment: Let's not delete the tag for now. It fits the question. Once we find a better fit, then sure.