# Is it possible to find out whether a tag has been removed by an automated process?

Tags: support, tagging, tag-management

A tag which exists only on one question is [automatically deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-pruning/info) after certain time [unless it has a tag-wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700).

Is it possible to check whether a tag have been removed by this process (because of being used on a single question)?

Specifically:

- If I remember the name of the tag, can I find out how it has been removed - manually or by the system?
- If I remember a question where this tag was used, can I somehow check whether a tag has been removed from this question by this process (and not manually)?

---

Here is a specific example. As mentioned [here on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10216/what-is-finiteness-tag-intended-for), the tag finiteness has been used in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436763/interesting-finite-cardinality-theorems). If I look at the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/436763/revisions), none of the edits show removal of this tag. The [first revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/436763/1) of the post is shown without tags. This seems to be different from the behavior of a tag which has been removed manually, for example, you can compare the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1451080/revisions) and the [first revision](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1451080/1) of another post, which uses a tag which no longer exists.

Is my guess that the [finiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finiteness) tag has been removed by an automated process correct? Would I be able to find this out without knowing that this question originally had [finiteness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finiteness) tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These removals are logged, but there's no easy way to look that up; you'd have to get an employee to search the logs for you.

The finiteness tag was removed on February 1st, 2014; it was removed from one post and 3 history entries by the monthly scheduled task that removes single-use tags after 6 months. That's all the information I have; critically, I can't tell you *which* post(s) had the tag prior to its removal.

Comment: Can you maybe tell someone else?

Comment: Tell someone else... what?

Comment: "I can't tell you which post(s) had the tag prior to its removal."

Comment: Oh. Lulz. No, because that information isn't recorded.